# How to pass a conditional string to command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, alias, string

I'm trying to alias my php command by executing it with an argument depending on if a file with my remote host IP is existant, without any additional argument otherwise.

I got it working with this version

```
#!/bin/bash
alias php="[ -f path/to/hostip ] && php -dxdebug.remote_host=\"$( < path/to/hostip )\" || php
```

Two issues

1. it's too long (luxury problem)
2. when calling `php path/to/any/script` my further arguments aren't passed to the php call

I tried a function, which solves issue #2

```
#!/bin/bash
function phpx {
    if [ -f path/to/hostip ]; then
        php -dxdebug.remote_host="$( < path/to/hostip )" "$@"
    else
        php "$@"
    fi
}
```

But I still have issues

1. it's much more longer (luxury problem)
2. I can't use `php` as the alias for the function name

What I'm looking for is an **alias** for `php` like

```
alias php='php ( condition | true > pass file content as argument | false > pass nothing )'
```

And I want to be able to pass my further arguments to the alias.

Comment: use `command php` instead of pure `php` in your script.

Comment: Thx. I didn't knew about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help command`:

```
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
    Execute a simple command or display information about commands.
```

So, run `command php "$@"` inside the function to not have it call the function again. Or `/usr/bin/php`, but then you need to know the correct path.

You could still use the `[ condition ] && php args.. || php other args` trick within the function, but note that it will run the latter `php` command also if the first `php` command fails, so the `if .. then .. else` is more correct. Of course you could write that as a one-liner too, but assuming you're saving the function to your `.bashrc` or such, the length shouldn't matter much
.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fallback if the first php call fails. Haven't thought about it. So the function is the only solution while if else is working correctly. Thx for the command example. Tried to dig into it and didn't got it in the first try.

Answer (score 0):

(This is really a comment, but needs formatting. Made it community wiki)

Note that (1)

```
A && B || C
```

is fundamentally different from (2)

```
if A; then B; else C; fi
```

in this situation: when A succeeds but B fails. When that happens, C **will run** in (1) but not in (2).

Comment: I got this with the answere of @ilkkachu. But nice you made examples. May you can be more specific with these examples - especially the logical order of (1)? I would edit your answere if you don't want to.

Comment: From the Lists section of the bash manual: "Of these list operators, && and || have equal precedence", so `A && B || C` is strictly left-to-right: `((A) && B) || C`. Adding the parentheses aids understanding B's effect on running C.

Comment: I know, but just didn't realized C will be invoked in two cases. Just wanted to mention, that you could enhance your answere to clarify all possibilities.

Comment: Community wikis are meant to gather the community's knowledge, so edit away.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make your alias look like this:

```
alias php='_php_opts=(); [[ -f /path/to/hostip ]] && _php_opts+=( -dxdebug.remote_host="$( < path/to/hostip )" ); php "${_php_opts[@]}"`
```

but why would you when you could write something readable that does not pollute the global variable namespace.

```
php() {
    local _php_opts=()
    [[ -f /path/to/hostip ]] && _php_opts+=( -dxdebug.remote_host="$( < path/to/hostip )" )
    command php "${_php_opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: This is a nice one, too. I didn't see `local` until now. Should be in the alias, too.

Comment: `local` is strictly for functions.